# Why does the processor get hot?

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, cpu

Good afternoon, I have Ubuntu 20.04 operating system installed. My laptop(Lenovo b590) is equipped with Intel i3 3110M, RAM 12Gb, SSD 256, HDD 512, Intel HD 4000 and Nvidia GT720. I can't understand why the system is stressing the CPU, Psensor shows a temperature of 60C at times the temperature can reach 70C. Nouveau drivers installed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX7e4.png)

Comment: **What** is stressing? What does `top -o cpu`say? Copy the the first 10 entries into your question.

Comment: A Laptop processor package temperature of 60 to 70 degrees is normal and nothing to be concerned about. When did you last clean the air vents? I have to clean mine about 2 times per year, and my environment is fairly clean.

Comment: I don't agree. Using a thinkpad the temperature should be around 40-50°C - thinkfan documents it for basically all device.   70°C is hot for laptop

Comment: For me it's `top -o %CPU` to see processes ordered by percentage CPU used. But 60c to 70c does not sound unreasonable to me. You can't really compare ideal/average temp between laptops as it will depend on many factors such as environment, CPU, laptop design etc. But my laptop under average load CPU is around 60c. Idle will be cooler. My max temps (e.g. in /sys/class/hwmon/hwmonx) are 84c and critical 100c See here for more info on what Intel say about temps: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005597/processors.html

Comment: @kanehekili Hello, I added a link to the result of the top command to the question

Comment: @DougSmythies I agree if the temperature would be in peak loads and not constantly, at startup the temperature is 40, but as soon as I start the browser, IDE, the temperature rises to 60-70, if I close all programs the temperature does not drop, also remains at 60-70. I think this problem is related to the video card driver, I cleaned the laptop a couple of months ago

Comment: @codlord The problem is that the laptop at idle gives 60-70, with no running chrome programs browser, ide, video

Comment: Additionally I installed tlp tlp-rdw, thermald, laptop-mode-tools, indicator-cpufreq and Psensor, but I do not see a decrease in temperature

Comment: Hi @DenisKataev I had the same issue and was the thermal paste I had to replace and make sure heat sink was making contact. Temperatures were down from 70s average to 45. I have to agree with doug-smyties.

Comment: @jpbrain Hi, Okay, a couple of months ago I was working on Windows 10, there was no such problem, the laptop was giving out 45C when idle and 55-69C when working. When I put my hand to the heatsink I felt warm, but not hot like now. I think the problem is in the video adapter, maybe it is stressing the system

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by several comments, if top/htop doesn't show any abnormal activity, then:

- The computer must be cleaned, including fans,
- The thermal paste should be replaced (for CPU, GPU and visible heat sinks).

Most of the time just a small philips screwdriver is needed, thermal paste is not expensive. If you have kids around they will be pleased to help. You will be amazed to see the amount of dust of different origin you can find inside.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the problem is in the hardware. Example: I run mozilla, temperature goes up to 60. run video all 70-79. Now I am working with Chromium the temperature is 53, if I close this browser the temperature would drop to 46-47, with mozilla the temperature would be at 60-65 after closing